# Getting TypeErrors And Dont Know Why

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So here is the error, this appears in the console when I issue the command, not when the bot starts. The bot starts normally:

```js
client.commands.get("accept").run(client, message, args);
                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'run')
```

**My code:**
Index File:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client({ intents: [30211] });

const prefix = "-"


const fs = require("fs"); 

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync("./commands").filter(file => file.endsWith(".js"))
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();  
for(const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

let myChannel = '908129511437127721' //target channel 

client.once('ready', () => { 
    console.log('Ready! - Made By Woodington');
});  

client.on('messageCreate', gotMessage);
function gotMessage(msg) {
    if (msg.channel.id !== myChannel) {
        client.channels.fetch(myChannel)
           .then(channel => channel.send(msg.content + `\n**User ID:** ${msg.author.id}\n` + `**Mention:** <@${msg.author.id}>`))
           .catch(console.error);
    }
};

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => { 
    if(message.channel.id == "908129528369532958"){
        message.delete()
    }
});   


client.on('messageCreate', message => {
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return; 

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase()

    if(command === "accept") {
        client.commands.get("accept").run(client, message, args);
    }
});
```

Command File:

```js
const {Client, Message, MessageEmbed} = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'dm', 
    /**
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {Message} message 
     * @param {String[]} args
     */ 
    run: async(client, message, args) => { 
        if(!message.member.permissions.has('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) return; 

        const user = message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])?.user 

        if(message.content.includes(-a)) {
            const str = args.join(' ').replace('-a', '') 
            user.send(str);
        } else {
            user.send(`Ticket Accepted By: ${message.author.tag}`)
        }
    },
};
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but I cant get it working. Im really unsure of why it puts out that error, and just to repeat the bot starts normally then does it after the command is sent. Thanks in advance for the help :)

Comment: Forgive the obvious question - before "_issuing the command the console_", did you define `client`, `message` & `args` in the console?

Comment: @RandyCasburn i dont issue the command in console thats where the error appears. I issue the command in discord

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a simple problem, your command is called `dm` as you can see in

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'dm',
```

Because it is called `dm` there will never be a command called `accept` so `client.commands.get("accept")` will return undefined, which you can't call `run()` on.

To fix this, you can change the command to "accept", or change the `if` statements to check for `dm`, i.e

```js
if(command === "dm") {
        client.commands.get("dm").run(client, message, args);
    }
```